# 'git add .' + 'commit -a' not working (changes are not staged for commit)

Tags: git

I usually commit my changes before **git push ...** by

```
git add .
git commit -a
```

after 2nd command a **nano** instance is usually launched in terminal (Linux Debian) to add a commit message.

However today after

```
git add .
```

if I do

```
git status
```

nothing is actually staged:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

**how do I fix this?**

I also tried with

```
 git commit . -m "commit_message"
```

Apparently (according to some other answer I found on SO) it could be due to my editor settings or whatever but I don't remember having done any change to them.

I also tried to change default editor used for commits by

```
 git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

but nothing changed. Also it seems the issue is not related to the **commit** command but to the **add** command.

**Also, how to avoid to do "git add ." manually when (except files/folders specified in .gitignore) I want to commit everything anytime?**

Comment: Have you tried `git add -A`  instead of `git add .`?

Comment: also try `git commit -m "message"` without the dot

Comment: Are you running `git add .` in the correct directory? That command stages only files that are located in the present working directory (or in one of its subdirectories).

Comment: I tried git add -A and git commit -m.
@Jubobs yes, it's the root directory with the .git folder

Answer (score 1):

I solved by

```
 rm -R sub_repository/.git
 git init
 git add .
 git commit -a
 git push origin master
```

Apparently removing .git directory cleaned up the mess with sub-repositories

Answer (score 1):

Your solution worked since you have removed all the data from the repository and recreated it again.

Once you did it its hard to figure out what went wrong.

I assume that you had files which were moved/renamed and you might have done it form the OS and not using `git mv` command.

Comment: what's wrong with using mv command instead of git mv? shouldn't git simply 'see the differences' in the directory structure (of course I'm not talking about .git directory. I never touched it. I have the feeling which could have either to with: sub-repositories (I always commit from the 'root' one) or some issue with bitbucket